# c#, unity - How to find index of list item, without predicate

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, predicate

```
int indext = lair.dungeon.DungeonLairList.FindIndex(x => x.name == lair.name);
```

That's my code, but I can't predicate, as lair objects can and will have the same names and it's very likely all other properties and it's crucial to determine the exact index in a list.

How can I do this?

Comment: If you're looking for the exact same instance, can't you just use `IndexOf`?

Comment: Thank you, totally got fixated on "FindIndex" :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var indext = Array.FindIndex(lair.dungeon.DungeonLairList, x => x.name == lair.name);
```